# Ruby - DataMapper - Form - Create New - Format of HTML to populate DateTime object in Model class

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

Ruby hashes are great and Ruby with DataMapper is even greater... This is regarding instantiating a DateTime property in Ruby using Hashes. It is involved with DataMapper.

I have a modal, `User` that has a birthday that is stored as `DateTime`

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  # Some other properties

  property :date_of_birth, DateTime

  property :gender, Enum[:male, :female, :other], {
    default: :other,
  }

  property :children, Integer
end
```

To populate the form I use some thing like this with HTML

```
<form method="post">

  <input type="text" name="user[name]" id="user-name">

  <!-- other fields -->

  <select name="{what to use for year?}" id="user-birth-year>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <!-- other options -->
  </select>

  <select name="{what to use for month?}" id="user-birth-month>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <!-- other options -->
  </select>

  <!-- Other fields -->
</form>
```

In the `register.rb` (route) I do some thing like this...

```
  post '/auth/register' do
    user = User.new(params['user'])
    # Other stuff
  end
```

As I understand, the has user has to kind of be similar to its fields. So how would the date_of_birth field be named to achieve this.

My assumption was to use some thing like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
:date_of_birth = {
  :year => '2010'
  :month => '11'
  :date => '20'
}
```

Which would be given by names `user[data_of_birth][year]` `user[date_of_birth][month]` and `user[date_of_birth][date]` for the select lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass assignment (doing `User.new(params['user'])`) isn't very good practice. Anyway, you need to obtain a `DateTime` or `Time` object somehow. You can name the fields how you want, for example:

```
<select name="user[date_of_birth][year]" id="user-date_of_birth-year>
  <option value="1980">1980</option>
  <!-- other options -->
</select>

<select name="user[date_of_birth][month]" id="user-date_of_birth-month>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <!-- other options -->
</select>

<select name="user[date_of_birth][day]" id="user-date_of_birth-day>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <!-- other options -->
</select>
```

and in your controller:

```
dob = DateTime.new(
  params['user'][date_of_birth][year].to_i,
  params['user'][date_of_birth][month].to_i,
  params['user'][date_of_birth][day].to_i
)
User.new(:name => params['user']['name'], :date_of_birth => dob, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info,I am curious to know why it may be bad. Is it like the user will post data that is not in the form manipulate the system other than the desired behavior (dumb ex: like get premium account without paying) It should work, I will test and accept it by tomorrow morning.

Comment: That is exactly the reason. Good luck with your project!